# Switch Case calculation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am having a problem in javascript and want to know if it is possible to do something like this or is it an error:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= nUnits.length; i++)
{
    switch (true)
    {
        case i % fDivisor === 0 && i % bDivisor === 0: //Note the modulus
            nUnits[i].push("FB");
            alert("FB");
            break;
        case i % fDivisor === 0:
            nUnits[i].push("F");
            alert("F");
            break;
        case i % bDivisor === 0:
            nUnits[i].push("B");
            alert("B");
            break;
        default:
            nUnits[i].push(i);
            alert(i);
            break;
    }
}
```

I have been looking around the web to see if I can do calculations on the case like this but all I see are expressions in the switch.

I also tried variants on it like this:

```
case (((i % fDivisor) === 0) && ((i % bDivisor) === 0)): //Note the modulus
    nUnits[i].push("FB");
    alert("FB");
    break;
case ((i % fDivisor) === 0):
    nUnits[i].push("F");
    alert("F");
    break;
```

I would like to know if this is actually valid syntax.

I understand that If statements may sometimes be better for this, but that is not the question. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Using `switch` like this is basically raping the language. It completely nullifies the advantages of a `switch`.

Comment: I'm trying to learn the proper syntax of switch cases. I already achieved success with if's. So again, its about if the syntax is allowed and correct vs does it look ok or practical. This is why I choose a simple problem. And I am trying it myself, I get no errors, but also no alerts. It simply does nothing. Hence the question.

Comment: If you want to learn the correct syntax (and semantics) of `switch`, just don't use it like this. There is nothing to learn in doing this. Learn `switch` with examples where it makes sense to use it.

Comment: @FrancisRodgers If you want to learn the syntax of a switch statement, use it the way it was intended, not some hacky way.

Comment: It makes sense to use case when choices are limited. Here the choices are limited. With regard to hacking, I want to know if case allows calculation. This is not hacky, it is a reasonable question as some languages do allow this.

Comment: @FrancisRodgers the main language I know which allows this is PHP, and PHP is famous for its poor design decisions. In this case, if you want to use switch, use `switch( ((i%f)===0)*2 + ((i%b)===0) )` and have 0–3 as your cases. It's a tiny bit more efficient than if/else that way, but still not as readable as if/else. Having equations in case statements is code smell even when it is valid according to the language.

Comment: There was a comment on an answer earlier that shows that it is allowed (while not necessarily recommended). It had a link to JsFiddle. Post as an answer and it will be accepted. Thank you.

Comment: @Dave thanks for the advice...can you post a link regarding info for this particular code smell or offer a description. I am interested in this.

Comment: The suggested link above does not contain an answer to this question. Thank you all for your help so far.

Comment: @FrancisRodgers I can't find a good link, but if memory serves, it's bad because it's essentially being used as a glorified goto (I know goto can be useful, but not in this sense). Also he linked question does have the answer (that it is valid according to the language but not recommended).

Comment: The linked question has logical comparisons (1 < 2) which equate to T/F. I know this is acceptable. My question asks if mathematical calculations (1 + 1 or 10 / 2) are allowed. This was not clear nor is it the same. Hence the question. Many languages allow the first, but not the second. I do understand now why it is not recommended to do this dave. Thank you.

Comment: Hmm, to a language, `1<2` and `1+2` are the same (in the sense of where you can use them), because `<` is just another operator. The distinction you see is between `1<2` and `1<a`. Some languages only allow the first (a "constant expression")

Comment: I was tempted to use letters instead of literal numbers in my last comment as I taught this might be the next comment! Instead of editing it (which will take daves comment out of context), I will just post saying I should have used letters instead. Thanks dave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see people are voting to close this valid question so I will answer it because I use SO for my own reference.

Another person posted an answer stating that this syntax in the case is incorrect and not allowed.

In a comment under that answer a poster provided a link to JSFiddle which proved that this syntax is correct. It may not be nice, but it is allowed. Then the person who posted the answer deleted it. Also removing the comment and the link. I hope the person providing the link will post it as an answer before the question is closed and I will delete this and accept his.

This answered my question. Which was:

Is "Calculations" (not logical operations) like this allowed in the case (not the switch). (NOTE the question was not to debate if it was good or not). But was it correct syntax, and is it allowed?

Regardless if you like it or not (SO is not a debating forum)...It is indeed allowed.

Comment: do you know how to do it? ive tried `case (calc < val):` but this doesnt seem to be working?